# How to re-render the value of form after updating in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a simple form and one input field has a dropdown items. When I select one of these , it change the category of product . But the problem is it does not reflect any change unless I have to refresh it.
Here is form:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer'
import { listProductDetails, updateProduct, categoryProducts } from '../actions/productActions'
import { PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET } from '../constants/productConstants'
import axios from 'axios'

function ProductEditScreen({ match, history }) {

    const productId = match.params.id


    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
    const [image, setImage] = useState('')
    const [brand, setBrand] = useState('')
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
    const [countInStock, setCountInStock] = useState(0)
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
    const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState(0)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const { error, loading, product } = productDetails

    const productUpdate = useSelector(state => state.productUpdate)
    const { error: errorUpdate, loading: loadingUpdate, success: successUpdate } = productUpdate

    const productCategory = useSelector(state => state.productCategory)
    const { error: errorCategory, loading: loadingCategory, products: productsCategory } = productCategory



    useEffect(() => {

        if (successUpdate) {
            dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET })
            history.push('/admin/productlist')
        } else {
            if (!product.name || product._id !== Number(productId)  )  {
                dispatch(listProductDetails(productId))
                dispatch(categoryProducts())
            } else {
                setName(product.name)
                setPrice(product.price)
                setImage(product.image)
                setBrand(product.brand)
                setCategory(product.category)
                setCountInStock(product.countInStock)
                setDescription(product.description)

            }
        }



    }, [dispatch, product, productId, history, successUpdate,category ])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(updateProduct({
            _id: productId,
            name,
            price,
            image,
            brand,
            category,
            countInStock,
            description
        }))
    }

    const updateCategoryHandler = async (categoryId) => {
        const formDataForCat = new FormData()


        formDataForCat.append('product_id', productId)



        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

            const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/products/category/update/${categoryId}/`, formDataForCat, config)


            // setCategory(product.category) it does not do anything
            console.log(data)

        } catch (error) {
            setCategory('')
           
        }
    }
    const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('image', file)
        formData.append('product_id', productId)

        setUploading(true)

        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

            const { data } = await axios.post('/api/products/upload/', formData, config)


            setImage(data)
            setUploading(false)

        } catch (error) {
            setUploading(false)
        }
    }


    return (
                 <Form.Group controlId='category'>
                                <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>


                                <Form.Control
                                    as='select'
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Enter category'
                                    value={category}
                                    onChange={(e) => updateCategoryHandler(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                    {productsCategory.map(product => {
                                        return (
                                            <option key={product.id} value={product.id}> {product.product_category}</option>

                                        );
                                    })}

                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
```

(NOTE: I HAVE SHOWN ONLY PARTS THAT ARE RELAVENT}

I have tried changing setCetegory and what I can according to my little knowledge.Any help??? It really waisted a lot of my time.

Comment: because you are not calling `setCategory(categoryId)` any where in this function `const updateCategoryHandler = async (categoryId) => {`

Comment: I did this but what happpend is , it is changed for a moment and then intsantly back to previous state(although it changed after refresh).

Comment: You need to call this `updateCategoryHandler` in `useEffect` hook else when you call setState the component is rerendered.